# Developing webapp with Intellij 15?

Tags: java, web-applications, intellij-idea

I've searched for the similar topic, but found nothing.

Is it possible to develop java WEBAPP with Community Edition of IntelliJ 15?

All i find are these links:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-web-application-support.html#new

But under "Additional libraries and frameworks" i see only groovy, maven and kotlin.

Does it mean i can only develop these kind of apps with ultimate edition ?

Sorry for the noob question, I've worked mainly with eclipse yet.
Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. Community edition does not support web development.

[image]